# How do i get date and time in points highchart?

Tags: php, highcharts, key-value, point

I plot highcharts on my page.
This works great but i have one little problem that in my points when i hover with my mouse on it, i get no date and time with it.

This is what my json is like.:

`[{"metingen":"metingen","Datum":"Datum","data":["5-9-2022",14.6,"5-9-2022",14.8,"6-9-2022",15.948,"6-9-2022",17.112,"6-9-2022",`

My chart look then like this.:

[image: highchart]

You see on the left the baloon, it show the number 0: 14.6.
14.6 is the value, thats good but the 0 is number of that value sutch as another point, that gives [image: baloon]

But how can i show the date and time thats belong with that number in the baloon?

My chart code is this.:

````
            $.getJSON("mfrmetingen300RG.json", function(data) {
                const processedData9 = [];

                for (let a = 0; a < data[0].data.length; a += 2) {
                    processedData9.push([data[0].data[a], data[0].data[a + 1]]);
                }

                data[0].data = processedData9;
                avg = <?php echo $rowj[0]; ?>;
                StDev = <?php echo $rowj[1]; ?>;
                Aantalwaarden9 = <?php echo $rowj[2]; ?>;
                //Cp=(USL-LSL)/(6xstd.Dev) see.:https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-cp-cpk-calculator.php
                //Cpk = (USL-gemiddelde) / (3 x std.Dev) of (gemiddelde-LSL) / (3 x std.Dev)

                cpkl1 = (<?php echo $_cpkh10waarde; ?>-<?php echo $_cpkl10waarde; ?>)/(6*StDev);
                Cpk1High = (<?php echo $_cpkh10waarde; ?>-avg)/(3*StDev);
                Cpk1Low = (avg-<?php echo $_cpkl10waarde; ?>)/(3*StDev);

                chart9 = new Highcharts.Chart('container9',{
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        type: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 100,
                        backgroundColor:'azure'
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        buttons: [{
                            text: '+',
                            events: {
                                click() {
                                    return false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: '-',
                            events: {
                                click() {
                                    return false
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    title: {
                        useHTML: true,
                            text: "Gemeten MFR waarde van PP 300R Grey Extrusie over de laatste "+(Aantalwaarden9)+" waarden.",

                         x: -20 //center
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    subtitle: {text: 'Gem.='+avg.toFixed(2)+' Stdev='+StDev.toFixed(2)+' Cp='+cpkl1.toFixed(2)+' Cpk_High='+Cpk1High.toFixed(2)+' Cpk_Low='+Cpk1Low.toFixed(2)+'',x: -20},
                    xAxis: {
                        uniqueNames: false,
                        type: 'category',
                        title: {
                            text: 'Datum'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        "min":15,
                        "max":23,
                        title: {
                            text: 'MFR'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }],
                        plotLines: [{value: <?php echo $_cpkl10waarde; ?>,color: <?php echo $_color_min_line; ?>,dashStyle: 'longdashdot',width: 2,label: {text: 'Minimum'}},
                                    {value: <?php echo $_cpkh10waarde; ?>,color: <?php echo $_color_max_line; ?>,dashStyle: 'longdashdot',width: 2,label: {text: 'Maximum'}},
                                    {value: <?php echo $_cpkm10waarde; ?>,color: <?php echo $_color_guide_line; ?>,dashStyle: 'shortdash',width: 2,label: {text: 'Richtlijn'}},
                                    {value: avg.toFixed(2),color: <?php echo $_color_avg_line; ?>,dashStyle: 'spline',width: 2,label: {text: 'Avg'}},
                        ]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>Meetwaarden</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {layout: 'vertical',align: 'right',verticalAlign: 'top', x: -100,y: 0,floating: true,borderWidth: 0},
                    series: data,
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                });
                chart9.legend.allItems[0].update({name:'MFR'});
            }, 1000);
        });```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `category` type xAxis, your category name is contained in `point.key` variable. So, based on your example, you only need to refer to `this.key`

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
      return '<b>Meetwaarden</b><br/>'+ this.key +': '+ this.y;
  }
},
```

**Simplified Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/87bousnL/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat

Comment: Yes that did the trick, but why if time is included with that date , will it also be taken in the balloon then?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. As far as the time will be provided in the same string, it will be shown as well https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8Ln9eyd0/ .  Perhaps you should consider using `datetime` `xAxis.type` in your project. It will need to be parsed to the timestamp format but is more appropriate to use it with dates.

Comment: I did test it after my question and indead i got date and time but sadly also in my x-axis and that is not what i want. Is there no solution to remove the time and show only the date in the x-axis?

Comment: The x-axis gives me now also date and time , same as the points. How can I show only the date in my x-axis. I tryed with this , but dos not work.: xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b/%e/%Y', this.value);
        }
      },},

Comment: Could you please reproduce your example in the working demo (use parsed data) ?

Comment: I did'nt solve my last question but this was also fine enouth for us.